# Counting previous Attributes with a specific value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wildcard

I apologize ahead of time if this isn't properly formatted, but...

I need to take the following xml:

```
<box r="?" c="?" b="?">
  <h r="?" b="2">
    <u>
      <v c="5" b="2">
        <l>
          <h r="?" b="1"/>
        </l>
        <r>
          <v c="?" b="?"/>
        </r>
      </v>
    </u>
    <d>
      <h r="?" b="2"/>
    </d>
  </h>
</box>
```

and using xslt:

```
<xsl:template name="BoxVariables-Count">
  <xsl:text>
        // Counting...</xsl:text>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*[@* = &quot;?&quot;]" mode="box-variable-count"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="local:*" mode="box-variable-count">
  <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:text>
        // </xsl:text></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
  <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="count((ancestor::local:box[1]/descendant-or-self::*[@* = &quot;?&quot;][position() &lt; $position + 1])/@*[@* = &quot;?&quot;])"/>
</xsl:template>
```

count the number of "?" attribute entries that occur before the current node in the box element. (As a note: the "?" is actually "Unknown")

The following line outputs the total number of attributes within nodes containing "?"s before the current node:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count((ancestor::local:box[1]/descendant-or-self::*[@* = &quot;?&quot;][position() &lt; $position + 1])/@*)"/>
```

outputs:

```
  // h = 3
  // h = 5
  // v = 7
  // h = 9
```

BUT, I want to only count the number of "?" attributes within that set.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count((ancestor::local:box[1]/descendant-or-self::*[@* = &quot;?&quot;][position() &lt; $position + 1])/@*[@* = &quot;?&quot;])"/>
```

outputs:

```
  // h = 0
  // h = 0
  // v = 0
  // h = 0
```

and I want:

```
  // h = 3
  // h = 4
  // v = 5
  // h = 7
```

In other words:

```
count(./@*[@* = &quot;?&quot;])
```

seems to return 0 and not the number of attributes within self that are set to "?".

It would be nice if I didn't have to write a recursive ? counter...

Comment: If you use `@*[@*='?']` with Saxon you will get a nice friendly message that attributes don't have attributes. Not sure what you were thinking of here.

Comment: Exactly! I though that was why. Attributes can't have attributes! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to me the simplest solution, and gives the wanted output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="box//*[@*='?']">
  <xsl:value-of select="'&#xa;//', name(), ' = ', 
     count((ancestor::*|preceding::*)/@*[.='?'])"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: very elegant - goes to show that xslt is very powerful and with a little thinking a brief but still very clear xpath expression may be constructed.

Comment: The actual implementation is for a Code Generator in C# where I need the index of the current ? in order to access an array of box variables inside a generated mutator method (get/set). I need the structure I have, for the most part (the // h = # will be replaced with a property/mutator method as output), but the [. = "?"] works perfectly! :D

Answer (score 1):

Is this the expression you need?

```
<xsl:value-of 
   select="count(preceding::*/@*[. = '?']) + count(ancestor::*/@*[. = '?'])"/>
```

So, given then following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="*[@*='?']">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('// ', local-name(), ' = ')"/>
      <xsl:value-of 
         select="count(preceding::*/@*[. = '?']) + count(ancestor::*/@*[. = '?'])"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#13;'"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/box">
      <xsl:text>// Counting...&#13;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output:

```
// Counting...
// h = 3
// h = 4
// v = 5
// h = 7
```

Comment: Perfect answer, but I'm not sure which one to accept. I apologize if I selected the wrong one. :)

Comment: Michael Kay's is the right one, don't worry! I'd accept that too!

Answer (score 0):

Different setup so may require restyling to be used in your xslt, but reaching the correct result:

```
<xsl:template match="/box">
    <xsl:variable name="qs" select="descendant-or-self::*[@*='?']"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$qs[not(local-name()='box')]">
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(($qs[position() &lt; $position])/@*[.='?'])"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

with result

```
h = 3
h = 4
v = 5
h = 7
```

Comment: Perfect answer, but again, I apologize if you were first and I didn't accept it. :)

Comment: @JoshuaWall not at all - Michaels solution is better and also more elegant

Answer (score -2):

The question mark is a special character in XPath, you should replace it with an XML entity. You should use `text()` to check the value of your attributes.

(Actually, I'm not sure about the question mark as it's within a string. It might not be necessary or even harmful...)

Try something like this:

```
count(@*[text() = '&#63;'])
```

Comment: Rubbish. A string literal in XPath-within-XSLT can contain anything except the delimiting quotes and the characters that are special in XML, `<` and `&`

Comment: The "?" is just for the example I wrote, to simplify it. The actual entry is "Unknown", as stated above. But thanks for trying! :D